# Javascript / convert CSS style string into JS object

Tags: javascript, regex

We'd like to convert a CSS style entered as string into a JS object.

E.g.,

```
 var input = " border:solid 1px; color:red ";
```

expected JS object :

```
 {
    border:"solid 1px",
    color:"red"
 }
```

Of course the number of style entries is unlimited as well as the names of style (border, color, font, z-index, etc...). Thx.

Comment: Testing shows, that only jAndy's and mjac's answers are working properly. The others forgot about whitespaces.

Comment: https://jsperf.com/style-tag-to-object comparison of some of the answers posted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the Javascript split function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

First split the string with `;` as the separator, and then for each result split with `:`, placing the items in an object as you go.

e.g.

```
var result = {},
    attributes = input.split(';');

for (var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
    var entry = attributes[i].split(':');
    result[entry.splice(0,1)[0]] = entry.join(':');
}
```

Comment: Won't work if there's a `':'` in the CSS value. E.g. `background-image: url('http://example.com/image.png')`. Fixed by splitting only on the first `':'`, e.g. `entry = attributes[i].split(/:(.+)/)`.

Comment: Short and simple but it doesn't handle spaces that well. Common css usage has a space after the colon, e.g `'background: red'` ... but this produces `{ background: ' red' }` (notice the unnecessary space before _red_)

Comment: This fails if `;` exists in a `content: "..."` property

Answer (score 10):

A very simple one:

```
var regex = /([\w-]*)\s*:\s*([^;]*)/g;
var match, properties={};
while(match=regex.exec(cssText)) properties[match[1]] = match[2].trim();
```

https://regex101.com/r/nZ4eX5/1

Comment: Just a note: it shouldn't matter much, but be aware that `match[2]` won't be trimmed on the right side. :-)

Answer (score 7):

## Stylesheet string to element style using JavaScript

Use just the string, [`CSSStyleDeclaration.cssText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/cssText):

```js
const styles = "color: #222; background: orange; font-size: 2em;";
document.querySelector("#test").style.cssText = styles;
```

```html
<div id="test">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

## JavaScript Implementation

If you need to convert a CSS style string to **Object**:

```js
const css2obj = css => {
  const r = /(?<=^|;)\s*([^:]+)\s*:\s*([^;]+)\s*/g, o = {};
  css.replace(r, (m,p,v) => o[p] = v);
  return o;
};

const cssObj = css2obj("color: #222; background: orange; font-size: 2em;");
console.log(cssObj);

// To apply use:
const elTest = document.querySelector("#test");
Object.assign(elTest.style, cssObj);
```

```html
<div id="test">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

In case you want to convert `dash-case` CSS properties to JS representations in `camelCase`, instead of `p` use `p.replace(/-(.)/g, (m,p) => p.toUpperCase())`

---

Oldschool JS:

```js
function cssToObj(css) {
  var obj = {}, s = css.toLowerCase().replace(/-(.)/g, function (m, g) {
    return g.toUpperCase();
  }).replace(/;\s?$/g,"").split(/:|;/g);
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i += 2) {
    obj[s[i].replace(/\s/g,"")] = s[i+1].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  }
  return obj;
}

console.log( cssToObj("color: #222; background: orange; font-size: 2em;") );
```

Comment: The first solution (JavaScript Implementation), unfortunately, does not yet work in Firefox

Comment: The javascript implementation doesn't work on safari because of lacking support to the lookbehind operator (?<=

Comment: @MazarD Some newest Safari version?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes, it's not supported by any safari version: https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind Safari is the new IE :(

Comment: @MazarD yeah, looks like. In that case the *"Old-school JS"* solution would work I think.

Answer (score 5):

In a functional form:

```
var styleInput = " border:solid 1px; color:red ";

var result = styleInput.split(';').reduce(function (ruleMap, ruleString) {
    var rulePair = ruleString.split(':');
    ruleMap[rulePair[0].trim()] = rulePair[1].trim();

    return ruleMap;
}, {});
```

Trim the strings before using them as object keys.

Comment: Trim isn't available in all browsers

Comment: @jondavidjohn Not all browsers are created equal. `({" trimmed":1}).trimmed` -> `undefined`

Comment: Trim requires JS 1.8.1 but that's outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score 3):

All the answers seem to need a lot of splitting- why not do a match and get all the pairs in one go?

```
function cssSplit(str){
    var O= {},
    S= str.match(/([^ :;]+)/g) || [];
    while(S.length){
        O[S.shift()]= S.shift() || '';
    }
    return O;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with splitting?  Yes, you could argue it takes (a bit) longer, but I doubt that we are talking about thousands of css properties here.  Even then, I bet that your match is similar computational intensity to `S=str.split(/[ :;]+/);`.

Comment: This solution will take longer, cause shift is slow. Code has less size, though.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun and for completeness…

I haven't checked cross-browser compatibility (only tried in Chrome), and it has some quirks:

```
var input = "font-weight:bold; color: blue; margin: 0 15px";

var e = document.createElement("div");
e.setAttribute("style", input);

var output = {};

for (var i = 0; i < e.style.length; i++) {
  var name = e.style[i];
  var value = e.style.getPropertyValue(name);
  output[name] = value;
}
```

The quirk is that even though we passed in a single `margin` declaration, we get an object like

```
{
  color: "blue",
  font-weight: "bold",
  margin-bottom: "0px",
  margin-left: "15px",
  margin-right: "15px",
  margin-top: "0px",
}
```

This might be a good or a bad thing depending on what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a tagged template literal syntax that works easily with React, you could do

```js
const camelCase = str => str.replace(/-(.)/g, (_,p) => p.toUpperCase())

const css2obj = (strings, ...vals) => {
  const css = strings.reduce((acc, str, i) => acc + str + (vals[i] || ''), '')
  const r = /(?<=^|;)\s*([^:]+)\s*:\s*([^;]+)\s*/g, o = {}
  css.replace(r, (m,p,v) => o[camelCase(p)] = v)
  return o
}

const center = 'center'

const reactInlineCSS = css2obj`
  align-items: ${center};
  justify-content: ${center};
`

console.log(reactInlineCSS)
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this should get you pretty close:

```
var input = " border:solid 1px; color:red ";
var output = '{' + input.replace(/([\w-.]+)\s*:([^;]+);?/g, '\n    $1:"$2",') + '\n}';
```

...turns

```
" border:solid 1px; color:red "
```

into

```
{ 
    border:"solid 1px", 
    color:"red ",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my function to convert CSS string to object:

```
function cssConverter(style) {
    var result = {},
        attributes = style.split(';'),
        firstIndexOfColon,
        i,
        key,
        value;

    for(i=0; i<attributes.length; i++) {
        firstIndexOfColon = attributes[i].indexOf(":");
        key = attributes[i].substring(0, firstIndexOfColon);
        value = attributes[i].substring(firstIndexOfColon + 1);

        key = key.replace(/ /g, "");
        if(key.length < 1){
            continue;
        }

        if(value[0] === " "){
            value = value.substring(1);
        }

        if(value[value.length - 1] === " "){
            value = value.substring(0, value.length - 1);
        }

        result[key] = value;
    }

    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use a third-party library such as [style-to-object](https://www.npmjs.com/package/style-to-object). For example:

```
import parse from 'style-to-object';

const input = " border:solid 1px; color:red ";
parse(input); // => {border: "solid 1px", color: "red"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function works even when there are `;` inside single or double quotes. Ex: `content: "data;"`.

```
function inlineStylesToObject(styles: string) : Record<string, string> {

  const regex = /([\w-]+)\s*:\s*((?:(?:"[^"]+")|(?:'[^']+')|[^;])*);?/g;

  const obj : Record<string, string> = {};

  let match;
  while (match = regex.exec(styles)) {
     obj[match[1]] = match[2].trim();
  }

  return obj;

}
```