# Use inline style in React with plain CSS string

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am rewriting an existing App which was based on AngularJS in ReactJS. In the App the user has the possibility to provide a CSS style string to style certain elements. In AngularJS this was no problem, I just set the 'style' attribute to the given string. In ReactJS I cannot do this anymore, because ReactJS requires a style object. I do not want to change the behavior of the application and require users to now provide a ReactJS compatible style object. Is there any way in ReactJS to just use a plain CSS style string to set the style of an element?

Comment: Convert the style string to javascript object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518956/javascript-convert-css-style-string-into-js-object

Comment: This will not help, I think, as the ReactJS object has camelCase keys that differ from the CSS keys.

Comment: Modify the converter to handle camel case.

Comment: That maybe possible, but I actually hoped that there is a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: I'm a little late to this party, but absent transforming the string into an object, the only other "clean" solution I can see is to use react to generate a `style` tag with the contents of the provided string.

Answer (score 18):

You can set the style string with `setAttribute('style', ...)` in [componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount) and [componentDidUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate).

You just need to be able to get a reference to the DOM node that React created. You can use [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) for that.

Here's an example. This component accepts a `styleString` prop, and sets it as the style on the `<div/>` that it renders.

```
import React from 'react';

class StyledDiv extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.refs.theDiv.setAttribute('style', this.props.styleString);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.refs.theDiv.setAttribute('style', this.props.styleString);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref="theDiv" />
    );
  }
}
StyledDiv.propTypes = {
  styleString: React.PropTypes.string,
};
export default StyledDiv;
```

Answer (score 8):

This is a hack I found for reagent, but I believe it'll work equally well for raw react versions >= 16 (where custom dom attributes are passed threw).  Just use the upper case `STYLE` attribute instead of lower case `style`, which is intercepted by React.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using `styled-components` then don't even bother looking at the other answers. With v4 you can literally just pass a string to the css prop to any html tag or a styled component.

```html
<div css="margin-top: 4px;">
Yes it works just like that :).
</div>
```

And guess what you don't even need to import `styled-components`. All you need to do is add [this](https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#babel-plugin) babel plugin. It turns any element with a css prop into a styled component.

Read more [here](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css-prop).

Answer (score 3):

Made a module that can handle this called [Style It](https://github.com/buildbreakdo/style-it) easy peasy, think we should all get back to simply writing CSS.

Just pass in the style string as a prop.

`npm install style-it --save`

**Functional Syntax** ([JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y2pnqh9e/37/))

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Style from 'style-it';

class Intro extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return Style.it(
      this.props.cssText,
      <p className="intro">CSS-in-JS made simple -- just Style It.</p>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Intro cssText=".intro { color: red; }"/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**JSX Syntax** ([JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y2pnqh9e/36/))

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Style from 'style-it';

class Intro extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Style>
      {this.props.cssText}

      <p className="intro">CSS-in-JS made simple -- just Style It.</p>
    </Style>
  }
}

export default Intro;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Intro cssText=".intro { color: red; }"/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

complementing taylor michels' answer

```
function CSSstring(string) {
  const css_json = `{"${string
    .replace(/; /g, '", "')
    .replace(/: /g, '": "')
    .replace(";", "")}"}`;

  const obj = JSON.parse(css_json);

  const keyValues = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
    var camelCased = key.replace(/-[a-z]/g, (g) => g[1].toUpperCase());
    return { [camelCased]: obj[key] };
  });
  return Object.assign({}, ...keyValues);
}


return <div style={CSSstring("margin-top: 4px; top: 100px")}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Convert the style string to javascript object

this was the solution for me. I had a json object generated like this

```
const generatedStyles = {
    "background-image": "url(\"http:/someurl/foo.JPEG\"), 
    "background-size": "auto 30px",
    "background-position": "center center"
}
```

I needed a method to convert this to a new object with camelCased keys for react-styles object. I have defined this in my component.

```
renameKeys(obj) {
    const keyValues = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
        var camelCased = key.replace(/-([a-z])/g, function (g) { return g[1].toUpperCase(); });
        return { [camelCased]: obj[key] };
    });
    return Object.assign({}, ...keyValues);
}
```

and can be used in the render like `<a style={this.renameKeys(generatedStyles)}>styled link</a>`

Comment: clean use of replace and regex, would've suggested lambda too, `var camelCased = key.replace(/-[a-z]/g, g => g[1].toUpperCase());` parentheses around [a-z] is unnecessary unless you're using the second parameter for the replacer function