# Copying styles from a DOM element to a React component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to copy the CSS styles from a DOM element so they can be used on a React component. It seems like there are several steps that need to be taken here:

1. Get the computed style of the DOM element to copy with `window.getComputedStyle`
2. Convert the resulting `CSSStyleDeclaration` into a React property, which entails camelcasing the CSS style entries and placing them into another oeject.

I've tried a variety of ways to do these steps, the latest of which involves the (seemingly popular) [`css-to-react-native`](https://github.com/styled-components/css-to-react-native) package. Here's what I've got so far:

```js
    const sourceElement = findElementById('someId');

    const styleTuples: [string, string][] = [];
    if (sourceElement) {
      const styles = window.getComputedStyle(sourceElement);
      Array.from(styles).forEach((property) =>
        styleTuples.push([property, styles.getPropertyValue(property)])
      );
    }

    const styleProperties = transform(styleTuples);
    return (<span style={styleProperties}>some text</span>)
```

However, when I do this, I get an error for `Error: Unexpected token type: word`. Any hints on the right direction to go here?

I've seen the answers for questions on how to copy CSS from one DOM element to another DOM element, but I think it's massaging the CSS into the particular format that React wants that is giving me trouble here.

Comment: [This answer may be what you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35143483/14068785)