# How to change all of a div's style attribute using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on my own in browser live HTML/CSS code editor.  What I'm having trouble with is applying the css styles typed out by the user to my div preview pane.

What I currently have is

```
   <html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Code Editor</title>
    <style>
        .wrapper{
            width: 100%;
        }
        .textWrapper {
            width: 30%;
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
        }
        #css{
            height: 300px;
            width: 100%;            
        }
        #html {
            height: 300px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #preview {
            height:600px;
            width: 400px;
            float:left;
            border:2px solid black;
            margin: 20px;
        }


    </style>

</head>
    <body>
    <div class ="wrapper">
        <div class ="textWrapper">
        <textarea placeholder="CSS..." id="css"></textarea>
        <textarea placeholder="HTML..." id="html"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="preview"></div>
        <button onclick="launch()">Launch</button>
        <button onclick="toggleCSS()">Toggle</button>
        <button onclick="clear()">Clear</button>

        <script src="bebk9hScripts.js"></script>
    </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

and for my script page

```
function launch() { 
    document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = document.getElementById("html").value;
} 


function toggleCSS() {

    document.getElementById("preview").style = document.getElementById("css").value;
}
```

but that is not working.  Any suggestions? Also I realize using an iframe would be easier but we aren't supposed to.

Comment: [Take a look at this answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518956/javascript-convert-css-style-string-into-js-object)

Comment: Don’t forget, if an answer solved your problem, the remember to mark your question as answered by clicking the check mark available on the answer to your question. Again, welcome to Stack Overflow and great first question!

Answer (score 4):

A simple and effective way to accomplish what you're trying to do is to set the `innerHTML` of your `preview` element. This does not prevent you from utilizing HTML, CSS, or JavaScript in any way, so long as all necessary dependencies have been accounted for prior to your `preview` element. The simple implementation is:

```
  var preview = document.getElementById("preview");
  var html = document.getElementById("html").value;
  var css = document.getElementById("css").value;

  preview.innerHTML = html;
  preview.innerHTML += '<style>' + css + '</style>';
```

However, as a developer in a very rapid environment, I can honestly say, using an interval to refresh the preview is much appreciated when you're trying to quickly update things. It'll be up to you as to how fast of an interval you'll use to refresh, or you could give your users a setting for update intervals.

Keep in mind though, that using intervals can cause undesired behavior such as animations being cutoff, etc. This is why a lot of code editors online use a *refresh* or *run* button in the first place. But I'd like to point out the usefulness of utilizing the `keyup` event that is available to us.

Coupling the `keyup` event with a timer, a manual refresh button, and an interval would be my recommendation:

```js
var html = document.getElementById("html");
var css = document.getElementById("css");

// Use the `keyup` event as a primary check for updates.
var keyDelay = 1000;
var keyRecieved = false;
var timeSinceLastKeyRecievedInMilliseconds = 0;
document.addEventListener('keyup', prepareForRefresh);
function prepareForRefresh() {
 keyRecieved = true;
 timeSinceLastKeyRecievedInMilliseconds = 0;
}
function update() {
 var preview = document.getElementById("preview");
   preview.innerHTML = html.value;
   preview.innerHTML += '<style>' + css.value + '</style>';
}

// Use an interval for checking if we should update.
setInterval(function() {
 if (keyRecieved) {
  timeSinceLastKeyRecievedInMilliseconds += 100;
  if (timeSinceLastKeyRecievedInMilliseconds >= keyDelay) {
   timeSinceLastKeyRecievedInMilliseconds = 0;
            keyRecieved = false;
   update();
  }
 }
}, 100);

// Use a high interval as a fail-safe for flukes.
var interval = 180000;
setInterval(update, interval);
```

```css
input[type=text] {
 margin: 5px;
 background-color: #fffa;
 border: 2px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
.update {
 width: 20%;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 5px;
 background-color: #f33a;
 cursor: pointer;
 user-select: none;
}
.primary-content {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}
html, body { overflow-y: auto; }
```

```html
<link href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2940219/PerpetualJ.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="primary-content" class="primary-content">
 <input id="html" type="text" placeholder="HTML" />
 <input id="css" type="text" placeholder="CSS" />
 <div class="update" onclick="update();">Refresh</div>
 <div id="preview"></div>
 <div id="refresh-preview"></div>
</div>
```

The simple example above utilizes a combination of the `keyup` event, a timer for detecting how long it's been since the user provided input, and a high interval as a fail-safe. This is close to the method utilized by CodePen, and I heavily recommend it for a web focused editor. Feel free to check out my implementation of this in it's simplest form over [on CodePen](https://codepen.io/PerpetualJ/pen/pozYoPp).

Comment: If you had used `input` event instead of `setInterval` I'd give you +1.

Comment: Yes, please use `onchange` on the code input elements to update the preview. Otherwise, very fancy solution.

Comment: @jmb I actually recommend the `keyup` event for initializing an update, but I prefer to couple it with a timeout on the user's typing to ensure I'm not constantly updating while they're typing. I'd also throw in an interval at every 2 or 3 minutes to refresh the page just in case of flukes, but that's just me. Cleaning up my answer currently.

Answer (score 2):

**Your Code works!**

**EDIT**: Well, at least kind of. It applies the styles directly only to the `preview` element, not its children (see comments below this post).

---

Below ist my old answer:

There is nothing wrong with it, and the issue must be somewhere else.
Possible issues that come to mind are:

- The CSS entered by the user is not valid, or is overwritten by another stylesheet
- The Javascript function to update the file does not get triggered
- The elements referenced in the Javascript are the wrong ones

Here is minimal working example using your code:

```js
function toggleCSS() {
    document.getElementById("preview").style = document.getElementById("css").value;
}

document.getElementById("apply_css").onclick = toggleCSS;
```

```html
<textarea id="css" cols="40" rows="5">
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: rgb(170, 200, 250);
</textarea>
<br>
<button id="apply_css">Apply CSS!</button>
<br>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I really cannot seem to figure this out though, as what I'm doing seems very similar to what you said would work.  I've added in the entirety of my code to the question if you wouldn't mind taking a look and seeing what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Oh! I think the problem might be that you want to apply styles to the child elements of `preview`, not `preview` itself! But the CSS you put in the `.style` attribute will only be applied to the element itself. The most it can do is get inherited by the child elements.

Comment: Ya my goal is to apply the CSS to the innerHTML inside the element itself, any suggestions on how to do that I can't find anything anywhere.

Comment: @BenjaminBradshaw Please review my answer below about using `innerHTML` if that's the path you wish to take.

Comment: Yes, using a `<style>` element is definitely the way to go here.